# KeyboardVisibilityPlugin - simple name is already defined

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Everything worked fine, but after upgrading packages I have got this error. BUT when I reverse the pubspec.lock I have got the same error...

```
    Projects/app/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:23:
error: a type with the same simple name is already defined by the single-type-import of KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
        import com.github.adee42.keyboardvisibility.KeyboardVisibilityPlugin;
        ^
        1 errorGradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you run `flutter clean' before upgrading plugins?

Comment: No, I didn't.. should I?

Comment: Yes. this looks like there is a duplicate  a of  KeyboardVisibilityPlugin intalled. Hope running `flutter clean` will solve this issue

Comment: Me also having this issue. I did run flutter clean but without any success.

Comment: I tried flutter clean many times. Now I tried reverse pubspec.lock run flutter clean and then run flutter pub upgrade. But I have got the same error message..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
1) Search for keyboard_visibility plugin used in your added plugin.
2) Remove or contact the author for the fix this issue.
3) run flutter clean.

This way I solved the issue.

Comment: How can I check it? in pubspec.lock I see flutter_keyboard_visibility plugin and keyboard_visibility plugin. But I don't know which plugins are using.

Comment: You have to check the dependency which has keyboard_visibility for all of your plugins which are added in the project.

Comment: Ok, is there some chance to find plugins what using this dependency? Because I have too many plugins..

Comment: The main advantage I had is that my first plugin on the list used that plugin